# Not able to set and remove the parameter to the Storage in the Ionic App

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, local-storage

I am working on the Ionic Ecommerce app and when the user login, after that I am setting the User id to the Storage and when the user clicks on the logout button it will remove the Storage but it is not setting the parameter to the Storage.

This is my **loginpage.t**s:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, AlertController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RestapiProvider } from '../../providers/restapi/restapi';
import { RegisterPage } from '../register/register';
import { CartPage } from './../cart/cart';
import {ForgetpasswordPage} from '../forgetpassword/forgetpassword';
import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyApp } from './../../app/app.component';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-loginpage',
  templateUrl: 'loginpage.html',
})
export class LoginpagePage {
  todo : FormGroup;
  responseData : any;
  userData = {"username": "", "password": ""};
  user: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    public restProvider: RestapiProvider, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private alertCtrl: AlertController, public events: Events, private storage: Storage) {
      this.todo = this.formBuilder.group({
        username: ['', Validators.required],
        password: ['', Validators.required],
      });

  }

  createUser(user) {
    this.events.publish('user:created', user);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginpagePage');
  }

    getloginUsers(){
      this.restProvider.getUsers(this.userData, 'user_Login').subscribe((data) => {
        if (data) {
          this.responseData = data;
          this.user = this.responseData.msg.name;
          this.storage.set("ID", this.responseData.msg.id);  <!-- I am setting the User Id to the Storage -->
          this.createUser(this.user);
          if (this.responseData.status === 'success') {
            this.navCtrl.push(MyApp);
          }
          else{
            this.presentAlert();
          }
        }
      });
 }

 presentAlert() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Incorrect Username Or Password',
    buttons: ['Dismiss']
  });
  alert.present();
 }
}
```

When the user login, I am setting the User Id in the Storage.

This is my **app.component.ts**:

```
import { LoginpagePage } from './../pages/loginpage/loginpage';
import { FrontPage } from './../pages/front/front';
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Events, Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { ProductPage } from '../pages/product/product';
import { MyordersPage } from '../pages/myorders/myorders';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  menuclick: boolean = true;
  menuclick2: boolean = false;
  rootPage: any = FrontPage;
  uemail: string;
  userName1: string;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any, name2: string}>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen, public events: Events, private storage: Storage) {
    this.initializeApp();
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Home', component: FrontPage, name2: 'home' },
      { title: 'Product Categories', component: ProductPage, name2: 'basket' },
      { title: 'Merchandise', component: ProductPage, name2: 'man' },
      { title: 'My Orders', component: MyordersPage, name2: 'cart' },
    ];

    this.events.subscribe('user:created', (data) => { // update from login
      this.userName1 = data;
      this.menuclick2 = true;
      this.menuclick = false;
 });

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }

  loginpage2()
  {
    this.nav.push(LoginpagePage);
  }

  logoutClicked() {
    console.log("Logout");
    this.storage.remove("ID");  <!-- I am removing the set item from the Storage  -->
    this.nav.setRoot(FrontPage);
    this.userName1 = null;
    this.menuclick2 = false;
    this.menuclick = true;
  }

}
```

When I am checking the User Id in myorders.ts, it is not returning any value:

This is my **myorders.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CartPage } from './../cart/cart';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-myorders',
  templateUrl: 'myorders.html',
})
export class MyordersPage {
  userhas: boolean = false;
  usernot:  boolean = true;
  newuserid: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private storage: Storage) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad MyordersPage');
  }

  public GetUsername(){
    if(this.storage.get("ID"))
    {
      this.userhas = true;
      this.usernot = false;
      this.newuserid = this.storage.get("ID");
    }
  }

  cardpage2()
 {
   this.navCtrl.push(CartPage);
 }
}
```

This is my **myorders.html**:

```
 <p>{{this.newuserid}}</p>
```

In this app.component.ts, I have the logout function where the User Id is removing from the Storage but the problem is that I am not able to set and remove the Item from the Storage. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Not related... Why are you using localstorage? Ionic has its own storage :) https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

Comment: Hi, first i don't understand why you are using windows.storage instead of ionic storage ?
https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/
second inonic storage is a promise so to add and check if exisit you need to use logic on then   eg  .
  storage.get('age').then((val) => {
    console.log('Your age is', val);
  });

Comment: @AJT_82. If I have used the local storage, Can i achieve this.

Comment: @JehadAhmadJaghoub. If I have used the local storage, Can i achieve this

Comment: @AJT_82. Can you tell the answer using Storage in the place of Local Storage?

Comment: @JehadAhmadJaghoub.  Can you tell the answer using Storage in the place of Local Storage?

Comment: @Raghav, kindly look at the documentation linked. There is `set` and `get` functions in using `Storage`. There is really nothing else to it :)

Comment: @AJT_82. I am trying, if I get some error I will update my question. Thanks.

Comment: @Raghav, please do. Also if you face an issue, please create a small stackblitz that reproduces the issue and I'd be happy to take a look. But let's hope it doesn't come to that! :D

Comment: So what is the error that you see when you say you can not set new value?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko. Like no error is coming but when I click on the logout button and after that when I again login, it is not setting any value. That's the problem.

Comment: so how do you know that it is not setting any value?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko.When I first login it is showing the value but after the logout and then login it is not showing the value.

Comment: OK so can you please put a console log into this method: getloginUsers() and run your app cycle and ensure that the value of this.responseData.msg.id is not undefined? can you also show what and how getloginUsers() is called.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko. this.GetUsername() in the Html and this.responseData.msg.id is defined because It is also showing the name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186878/discussion-between-raghav-and-sergey-rudenko).

Comment: @SergeyRudenko.The problem is that after first login it is showing the value but after logout and again login it is not showing the value.

Comment: @AJT_82. I have updated my question and I have used the Storage but it is not setting any value. Can you please help?

Comment: @AJT_82. Thank you for the suggestion and I have solved my query.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko. Thank you for the suggestion and I have solved my query.

Comment: @JehadAhmadJaghoub. Thank you for the suggestion and I have solved my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 this.storage.remove("ID").then(() => {
    this.userName1 = null;
    this.menuclick2 = false;
    this.menuclick = true;
    this.nav.setRoot(FrontPage);
  });
```

storage.remove returns a Promise, wait for it before doing other stuff.

Also try to setRoot after cleanup coommands...

Comment: I am also not able to set the value of the User id. I have done this code: public GetUsername(){
    if(this.storage.get("ID"))
    {
      this.userhas = true;
      this.usernot = false;
      this.newuserid = this.storage.get("ID");
    }
  }

Comment: Thank you for the answer but can you help me with this code. if(this.storage.get("ID"))
    {
      this.userhas = true;
      this.usernot = false;
      //this.newuserid = this.storage.get("ID");
      this.storage.get("ID").then((val) => { console.log('Your age is', val); });
    }

Comment: this.storage.get('ID').then((val) => {
    if(val) { this.userhas = true; this.usernot = false; this.newuserid = val; } 
  });

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It has solved my query. Thanks.